# A semantic comparison between the usage of two prepositions 'from' and 'than' in American English

Tags: american-english

I appreciate it if dear Americans of the forum could help me with the sentences bellow:

> - American English is very different **from** British.
> - American English is very different **than** British.

I know both the bold prepositions above are used in AE and in this sense; but the question is that if they make any difference in the sentence's implication or they are interchangeable in this context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference in meaning; it's a matter of personal choice in Both British and American English. You might find these Ngrams for [British](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=different%20from%2Cdifferent%20to%2Cdifferent%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20than%3B%2Cc0) and [American](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=different%20from%2C%20different%20to%2C%20different%20than&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20from%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdifferent%20than%3B%2Cc0) English interesting.

Comment: Thank you very much, but as far as I am concerned, the British version, most often, uses 'to' instead of these two prepositions. Am I right Tunny? ;)

Comment: @ A-friend - No. The Ngram suggests that 'from' is far more common in BrE than the other two. This is confirmed by the British National Corpus, which has 3,246 citations for 'from', 475 for 'to' and 50 for 'than'.

Comment: But Britons might say *to,* whereas AmE speakers would not.

Comment: Exactly @CarSmack. :)